# Send dm to several people in slack using google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, webhooks, slack, slack-api

i want to send dm to several people in slack using google script. i have all their webhooks. but i dont know the code to send it using several webhooks.

message error :
Exception: Invalid argument: [https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX,https://hooks.slack.com/services/YYYYY]

````
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ji = ss.getSheetByName('Mailer');
  var url = "[https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX,https://hooks.slack.com/services/YYYYY]";
  var ji_ticket =ji.getRange(3,3,ji.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues();
  var linkticket = ji.getRange(3,4,ji.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues();
  var total_ticket = ji.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var status = ji.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var payload = 
  {
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": ":bell: *Pending Ticket* :bell:"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "divider"
      },
      {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text":
              "Hi Leaders,\n\n"+ 
              "There are " +total_ticket+ " tickets pending. Kindly click this tickets: "+linkticket
              //"\n\n\nThankyou"
        }
      }
    ]  
  };

Logger.log(payload)
  var params = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  if(status=='Yes'){
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)` can only fetch a single URL per call, so you can try to call the API for each webhook.

```
var url1 = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX";
var url2 = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/YYYYY";
...

UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1,params);
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,params);
```

**Reference:**

[Class UrlFetchApp | fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)